# How to Exclude protected Operating system files in search

Tags: c#, file, search, directory

(Using windows 7 64bit and C#)

Is there any way to exclude these protected files from your search?

This is Showing ALL the files in the folder including the "System Files"

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(directory);
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
var list = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\").GetFiles()
                .Where(f => !f.Attributes.HasFlag(FileAttributes.System))
                .Select(f => f.FullName)
                .ToList();
```

Comment: @SonerGönül Of course, I tested it before posting. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.hasflag(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Confirmed working, Thank you. Really neat way using lambda expression.

Comment: Okay - just to educate a little: `f => f.FullName` is a lambda expression. `list.Where().Select().ToList()` is linq method syntax.

Comment: ... educate and be *annoying*, that's my forté!

Comment: haha Thank you. Like that one saying goes "I've never in my life learned something from any one who agreed with me"

Comment: (Oh and why I thought it was lambda, is that if you insert that snippet of yours while debugging, it lets you know it wont be able to execute your code before you restart because "adding a statement that contains lambda will ... your debug session" =)  )

Comment: I got an error using this, but @esskars solution worked for me. The error was The error was: "'System.IO.FileAttributes' does not contain a definition for 'HasFlag' and no extension method 'HasFlag' accepting a first argument of type 'System.IO.FileAttributes' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Answer (score 2):

You can use [FileInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx).

```
var fileInfo = new FileInfo(path);
if((fileInfo.Attributes & FileAttributes.System) != FileAttributes.System))
{
    // path is not a system file
}
```

Comment: The accepted answer caused an error for me, but this one worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Directory.GetFiles, as all other .Net framework methods that work with file system, does not use explorer settings. You can get FileInfo by path and then check the attributes to filter out hidden files yourself.

Answer (score 0):

For each file, you will have to check the file attributes as shown below

```
FileAttributes att = File.GetAttributes(@"c:\samplefile.dll");
```

and then use the following test

```
if ((att & FileAttributes.System) == FileAttributes.System)
{
    // the file is system
}
```